# Programmatically creating a 3d mesh in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, 3d-meshes

Surprise! Another question related to Minecraft. Anyways:

Rather than drawing thousands of blocks each frame, I remember reading somewhere that Minecraft breaks the map into 16x16x256 chunks, and every time one of the chunk's blocks is updated, it reconstructs a mesh for that chunk to be used in rendering. The idea is that you'll only ever see a handful of chunks at a time, which equates to only a few meshes being drawn.

This is all fine and well, but XNA doesn't seem to have built in support for creating meshes on the fly. It seems that my only option is to mess around with TriangleLists and the like. Is that the only option, or is there some alternative I'm not seeing?

Comment: Triangle lists are a way to dynamically generate a mesh, and a good option since you have lots of control over how the mesh is generated. This allows you to implement plenty of optimizations for performance later on.

Comment: You can with triangle list create cubes and with these cubes you can add as many as you want to a VertexBuffer and then you only draw one VertexBuffer per chunk and draw the closest cubes individually.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know. Other then that, what you can do it simply construct a cache of these files, of which you can draw meshes on and tell xna to read them. This may be sorta slow but I actually think Minecraft does it. It constantly reads and writes data files, doubt you game is gonna be slowed down.

Comment: This is really just a comment, not an answer.